# Airflow HttpSensor won't work

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to create a HttpSensor in Airflow using the following code:

```
wait_to_launch = HttpSensor(
    task_id="wait-to-launch",
    endpoint='http://' + socket.gethostname() + ":8500/v1/kv/launch-cluster?raw",
    response_check=lambda response: True if 'oui'==response.content else False,
    dag=dag
)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "http_sensor_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    dag=dag
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/decorators.py", line 86, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/sensors.py", line 663, in __init__
    self.hook = hooks.http_hook.HttpHook(method='GET', http_conn_id=http_conn_id)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py", line 436, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a known issue, see [AIRFLOW-1030](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1030). A fix has been merged ([#2180](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2180)), but unfortunately is not yet on a released version of airflow. The fix is marked for the next release (1.9.0), but it could be weeks/months until that is out. You can run a fork of airflow with this change or add the updated version of the HttpSensor as a custom operator (plugin).